# How to reference to array element when concatinating a string?

Tags: javascript

If I have:

```
var b1 = ["B", "V"];
```

I can access `"V"` with `b1[1]`;

Why does the following not work:

```
console.log(("b"+1)[1]);
```

I get 1 in console.

Answer (score 2):

If `b1` is defined in the global scope, you can access it as a member of the window object:

```js
// When variable is defined in global scope
var b1 = ["B", "V"];
console.log(window['b'+1][1]);

// Inside a function you're stuck with eval.
// You should be really, really careful with eval.
// Most likely you can change your design so you wont need it.
function test() {
  var b2 = ["B", "V"];
  console.log(eval(('b'+1))[1]);
}

test();

// Just to demonstrate that accessing an object's properties
// always works the same way
window['console']['log']('hi');
```

Comment: It's inside a function. I tried window.nameOfFunction but that doesn't work. Also can you explain what is that you did? How come you used [] for 'b'+1?

Comment: @stepbystep I've updated my answer. Basically, you can access any property of an object by putting the name inside brackets. Also note that property names are always strings, so `window['1']` and `window[1]` refer to the same property.

Answer (score 1):

You get 1 in console because `"b"+1` is formatted to string to `"b1"`. Index 1 in this string is character `1`.

Doing something you want is very bad idea. If you want to access these variables using numbers from other calls, use arrays `b = []` and then use b[index][subindex]` for your string.

Or use `window` scope variable.

Comment: **Don't** use arrays. If you want *named* properties, use plain objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you get that result**

When you concatenate (`+`) a String and a number, you get a String. Using the bracket notation on a String will get you the character at a certain index. In your case, `"1"`.

**How you can make it work**

If your `b1` variable is global (not defined inside a function), it is a property of `window`. So you can access it using `window["b"+1]`.

```js
var b1 = ["B", "V"];

console.log( window["b"+1][1] ); // "V"
```

If it's local (inside of a function), use an Object to store it:

```js
var scope = {};
scope.b1 = ["B", "V"];

console.log( scope["b"+1][1] ); // "V"
```